# Vue.js событие на изменение опции в элементе "select"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

никак не могу понять, как сделать событие на тот случай, когда пользователь меняет опцию в select... Вот пример:

```
<template>
    ...
        <select v-model="selectedTask">
             <option v-for="task in $root.$data.tasks">{{ task.title }}</option>
        </select>
    ...
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        ...
        data() {
            return {
                ...
                selectedTask : $root.$data.tasks[0].title,
                ...
            }

        },
        methods : {
            ...
                // Хотелось бы чтобы это метод срабатывал, когда пользователь выбрал другой option в select
                onChangeSelectedTask : function() {
                    alert("Selected: " + this.selectedTask);
                }
            ...
        }
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select v-model="selectedTask" @change="onChangeSelectedTask">
```